# How to set state in onChange when you pass down props to child component?

Tags: reactjs, state, onchange, react-props

I am having trouble assigning the state in my onChange function when I pass down props to a child component. I have a form that when the user submits it should update the state.

In the past, I have set state, but without passing props, since it was in the same file, but now that I am using props in a function, I am not sure how I would set state.

```
const Child = props => {
return (
<div className='form'>
    <Form >
        <Form.Row>
            <Col>
                <Form.Control 
                name="studentName" 
                value={props.studentName} 
                placeholder="Student name" 
                onChange={this.change}  
                />
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <Form.Control 
                name="studentId" 
                value={props.studentId} 
                placeholder="StudentID" 
                onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                />
            </Col>
        </Form.Row>
    </Form>
</div>
)}
```

Comment: This is a functional component. Initially, functional components were not able to use state, but you can now the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `callback function` to your Child component as a `prop`.

`props.onChange`

And then in your Parent component handle the state using `setState`.

Check this out for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Here you have an example:

```
const Child = props => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="studentName"
        value={props.studentName}
        placeholder="Student name"
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: ""
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      data: e.target.value
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.data);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <p>{`state: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}`}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If what you want is Child to handle its own state, then you either use React hooks and add state to a function component (see `useState` or `useReducer` hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate, or make it a class component.